# Debug Java web app on mobile phone

Tags: java, html, ios, google-chrome, debugging

I have Ubuntu on computer and iOS on a mobile phone. 
I was running the Java Web project on a laptop, and I have access to my page on mobile phone via address X.X.X.X:8080.

Is it possible to debug the application from the phone? I would like to put some breakpoint or check console log after clicking something on mobile.

I found Remote Debugging Android Devices (Chrome):
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
Is it possible to do something similar for IOS over Wifi?

Regards.

Comment: Are you trying to debug a web _page_ or a web _server_?

Comment: Only Web page..

Comment: use develop menu available in safari and connect your phone and debug

Comment: Basically, it's impossible on ubuntu without any emulator.